# array look-up in D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In D3.js (or in JavaScript in general) if you have an array like

```
var out = [
    {name:"John", car:"bmw", colour:"blue"},
    {name:"Joe", car:"ford", colour:"red"},
    {name:"Anna", car:"honda", colour:"green"},
    {name:"Mary", car:"bmw", colour:"red"},
];
```

how can I get `car`and/or `colour` for a given name please? The names can be considered as unique and the array doesn't necessarily have to be an array ie a dict should also be fine

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try d3.map, it will return an item in the data array given a key. It is created as follows:

```
 d3.map(array, function(d) { return d.key; });
```

You then access an item in the map with:

```
 map.get("value");
```

Or check to see if such a value exists:

```
 map.has("value");
```

See the [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-collection#maps) for more info.

Here's an example with your dataset:

```js
var out = [
    {name:"John", car:"bmw", colour:"blue"},
    {name:"Joe", car:"ford", colour:"red"},
    {name:"Anna", car:"honda", colour:"green"},
    {name:"Mary", car:"bmw", colour:"red"},
];


var map = d3.map(out, function(d) { return d.name; });

// Get items by key:
console.log(map.get("John").car);
console.log(map.get("Anna").colour);

// Check to see if an item exists:
console.log(map.has("Joe"));

// Create a new value and access:
map.set("Ralph", {name: "Ralph",car:"bmw",colour:"red"})
console.log(map.get("Ralph"));
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Of course you don't need to use d3 for this, regular ES6 maps (or a myriad of other options) can work just as easily:

```js
var out = [
    {name:"John", car:"bmw", colour:"blue"},
    {name:"Joe", car:"ford", colour:"red"},
    {name:"Anna", car:"honda", colour:"green"},
    {name:"Mary", car:"bmw", colour:"red"},
];

var map = new Map(out.map(function(d) {
  return [d.name,d];
}));

console.log(map.get("John"));
```

Comment: Ah yes! thanks! What I had put together (which is really laughable..) was myDict = d3.nest().key(function(d){return d.name}).entries(out)
temp = myDict.filter(function(myDict){return myDict.key=='Anna'})
ans = temp[0].values[0].car
console.log(ans)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `Array.prototype.find()` method, which will return the entire object including `car`, `colour`, and the given `name`.

**Example:**

```
var out = [
    {name:'John', car:'bmw', colour:'blue'},
    {name:'Joe', car:'ford', colour:'red'},
    {name:'Anna', car:'honda', colour:'green'},
    {name:'Mary', car:'bmw', colour:'red'}
];


out.find(function(item) {
    return item.name === 'John'
}

// will return the following:
{ name: 'John', car: 'bmw', colour: 'blue' }
```

You can also use an ES6 [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to achieve the same:

```
out.find(item => item.name === 'John')
```

> Here is the documentation for: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find).